# Simple mod write

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a simple mod_rewrite question.

What do I need to write in the .htaccess file to have:

> http://www.example.com/index.php?route=account/login

I want the URL to look like this

> http://www.example.com/account/login

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1
```

Comment: Mabye it's my wampserve. Doesn't seem to be working.  Modwrite module is turned on.